# IE element percentage width/max-width bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have run into a problem where IE is not rendering my page correctly.

Here is the site: [Cakeball Flavors](http://kelseyskreations.scordesigns.com/flavors)

**Google Chrome**
[image]

**Internet Explorer 11**
[image]

Basically I'm trying to make the `main` element 1000px wide, but internet explorer is failing to accomplish this. I'm utilizing max-width of 1000px and width of 100% for a fluid layout, but IE seems to be ignoring it. I've double-checked the code inspection in both browsers to ensure that nothing is overriding it.

**Markup**

```
...
<body>
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <main>
    <header>
      <h1>Flavors</h1>
    </header>

    <h2>Basic</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="...">
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    ...
  </main>
...
```

**Style**

```
...
body {
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: -1rem auto -1rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Is `main` a valid element? Did you try with a regular `div`? Or maybe set `display: block`?

Comment: `main` is html5. It also is `display: block`.

Comment: [`main`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) is not supported in IE yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @steveax, I was able to figure out the problem is IE's lack of support for the `main` element. After a further 30 minutes of research and testing I came up with a solution.

In my head tag, I added the following code above all my css links:

```
<script>document.createElement('main');</script>
```

In my stylesheet I added:

```
main { display: block; }
```

Now the page correctly renders in Internet Explorer (10 & 11 at least).

[image]